# Adding render props to functional React component children

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to add a render prop to all of the nested children in my component. When I use:

```
const doSomething = () => console.log('\\o/')

const ParentElement = ({ children }) => (
    <div>
        { children.map(child => React.cloneElement(child, { doSomething })) }
    </div>
)
```

I receive the error:

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `doSomething` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `dosomething` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```

Essentially, I'm trying to recreate something like this for each child:

```
const ChildElement = ({ doSomething }) => (<div onWhatever={doSomething}>...</div>)
```

What's the correct way to attach these render props?

Comment: Do you add `doSomething` to any DOM element?

Comment: Where is `doSomething` defined?

Comment: @DacreDenny `doSomething` is defined as a constant above the component definition. It's not something that I want exposed to the DOM, I'd just like to wire it to the inner React components logic.

Comment: How is `doSomething` actually used? Somewhere it's being added as a prop to a plain HTML element rather than a React component

Comment: @Jayce444 In practice, I'd like to pass in some methods and other variables. Things like this: https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Comment: @iRyanBell For my own knowledge, is `{ children.map(child => React.cloneElement(child) }`, without the extra prop, actually working? (I didn't know about `cloneElement`, it seems interesting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to just need to set the correct prop name (`{ doSomething }` is shorthand for `{ doSomething: doSomething }`), but you technically `children` are an opaque structure, so you probably also want to use `React.children`:

```
<div>
  {React.Children.map(children, child => 
    React.cloneElement(child, { onWhatever: doSomething })
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: That block throws: `TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default.a.children is not a function`

Comment: @iRyanBell Are you using it inside of the `Parent` functional component with a `children` prop as you show in your question? // Also, just noticed I didn't capitalize `React.Children` correctly at first; could be that.

Comment: This is inside a stateless functional component like the `ParentElement` example. If I use `React.Children.map(child => 
          React.cloneElement(child, { doSomething })
        )` I don't get the error, but I also don't see my children. With `React.Children(children)` it still throws that error.

Comment: @iRyanBell I goofed. You want to pass `children` as the first argument to `React.Children.map`, and the function to call as the second argument. Updated my answer.

Comment: `Warning: React does not recognize the 'doSomething' prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase 'dosomething' instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.` If I use the key `onWhatever` then it reports: `Warning: Unknown event handler property 'onWhatever'. It will be ignored.` This seems to be attaching the props to the component rather than providing them to the component's constructing function where the props are destructured and used internally.

Comment: @iRyanBell You have to replace `onWhatever` with the correct prop (e.g. `onClick`, or some custom prop). If the component you're passing the prop to passes it through to an element that renders a DOM element (e.g. `div`) then React is going to complain that it's not valid. This is as expected.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue now! My children are wrapped in another element. So, I suppose I'm actually trying to attach a prop to something like a child's inner React component rather than the child's main container The error that was being thrown was throwing me -- I guess this is because it was an html element and not the inner React child. I'll have to restructure my logic. Thanks for helping me walk through this.